# spyder showing missing dependencies

Tags: spyder

[image]

Just wondering if this is a spyder bug, or whether there was an update between yesterday and today? spyder was working fine for me yesterday. This error message showed up.

jedi=0.17.1: 0.18.0 (NOK)
parso=0.7.0: 0.8.2 (NOK)

Somewhat related, what do jedi and parso do, and what does "NOK" mean?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) My answers to your questions:

> just wondering if this is a spyder bug, or that there was an update between yesterday and today?

This is not a bug. It means that you have the wrong versions of some of our dependencies (as the message clearly states).

> spyder was working fine for me yesterday

You probably ran `conda update --all`, or installed another package with `conda` or `pip`, which updated Jedi and Parso as well.

To fix this problem, you need to reinstall those packages with the right versions. For that, please open the Anaconda Prompt or a system terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe`) and run **one** of the following commands:

`conda install jedi=0.17 parso=0.7`

if you're using Anaconda, or

`pip install jedi==0.17.1 parso==0.7.0`

if not.

> somewhat related, what do jedi and parso do, and what does "NOK" mean?

- Jedi provides code completion in the editor and Parso is used for code folding on it as well.
- `NOK` means `Not ok`.